# cakephp update field on session timeout

Tags: session, cakephp, session-timeout

I'm using database sessions in CakePHP, saving also the user id in the same table as the sessions. Is it possiblee to detect somehow when a user session expires so I can update one field in the database?

I need that in case the user doesn't log out manually from the website (just closes the browser or not even that) I can remove that session from the table.

Comment: Database sessions are automatically cleaned after a while, just like regular sessions. That's the point of them *timing out*. What exactly do you want to do manually here?

Comment: well, that's what I thought. I have the timeout to "1" (in medium security level, so 100 seconds timeout I believe). I've done a log in and I can see the record in the sessions database. I've been checking it for a while (more than 30 min) from MySQL admin, refreshing the page and trying to log in with the same username from a different location, but that record hasn't been deleted. It has finally been deleted after I've done a refresh of the database table.

Comment: So my question would be, how does the session timeout actually work for database sessions? What exactly triggers the event that deletes a record from that table? Does it need some access to the website? Or it just happens when the session expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session data cleanup relies on garbage collection (gc). This garbage collection process is only invoked when a PHP script runs, i.e. it's not cleaning up data right when it could be cleaned up, but some time afterwards when another PHP script is running. Since garbage collection also takes up some resources, it does not run every time, but there's a certain probability that it'll be run for each script invocation. [The default is that gc runs about once every 100 script invocations.](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability)

So you will not see stale data disappear immediately. Rather, it'll be cleaned out eventually.

Comment: Ok, so that means that once the session expires, those records in the sessions table will be eventually deleted without me having to create some code to do that right?

Comment: I've done another test, with the session timeout set to 14 (1400 seconds total). I've logged in, checked the sessions table and my session was there. I've left the computer for more than one hour and checked back the sessions table, and the same session was still there. The session had expired, because when I tried to go to another page I was prompted to log in (as it should). At this point, I checked the table and then the record with the old session had been gone. Shouldn't it have been gone way before?

Comment: Again, the garbage collection only runs every once in a while, and only when one of your PHP scripts runs. If none of your session-using PHP scripts run, the garbage collection won't run. And even then, only about 1 of every 100 script runs invokes the garbage collection. It's simply **cleared out eventually**, there's no guarantee when exactly it happens or that it'll happen anywhere near real-time. Garbage collection is a concept used a lot in computing, and it's always a low-priority, no-specific-timing-guaranteed process.

Comment: OK, I understand,I was asking because I was experiencing some weird behavior. When a user logs in, I save his id in the same sessions table along with the session id and data. But before doing that, I check that his username is not currently logged in (looking in that table). If his username is in that table, I deny the log in to avoid multiple users using one account at the same time. For this to work in a fair way for the user, it's important that the expired sessions are deleted from that table, which is not happening as I thought it would happen...

Comment: Why are you denying multiple logins? That's not typically useful on a website. Why can't I open another browser and log in simultaneously from two browsers? What if I close my browser, the session cookie is deleted, then immediately reopen my browser and try to log in again? The session will still be valid on the server, but I can't access it anymore and have to wait for it to timeout before I can log in again. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: It's a requirement from the client. Users pay for using this website, so they want to avoid multiple users at the same time. I was debating also blocking by IP instead of by Session, but after doing some research I choose the last one. AN alternative would be to let the new user log in and kick out the old one, that would solve some of the problems. However, if you have a better idea or a different approach I'm all ears of course!

Comment: I simply don't get the session restriction. If a *human* pays to use the site, he should be allowed to do so on as many devices as he wishes simultaneously with his account. It's one human paying for the privilege of using the site, not one machine. But then of course, I don't know anything about the wider business rules behind this...

Comment: Well, it's really not a matter whether I agree or not, it's just a requirement. I can understand they want to avoid that someone buys one membership and many people use it, they lose money. With this method at least you avoid that they can use it at the same time. Anyways, I'm going to use the IP blocking instead of session, your comments made me see that by session could be worse. Thank you very much for your help!